# Realtime Updates from Facebook in Windows Phone

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-7, facebook-graph-api, windows-phone, facebook-page

I am new to FB API and also Windows Phone 7.1/8. I am in need of immediate assistance to ***get a real time update of any pics that are posted on a specific page on a windows phone app***. I have to just show the count of new pics posted in that page on the tile.
I went through FB's realtime api and wherever I see I notice a **callback url** but where am I going to get a url in windows app?
It should be very easy task for many. So, please point me to right direction.

Comment: The callback URL would more than likely be used with a [push notification system](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402558(v=vs.105).aspx), which in turn, sends a message to that particular instance of the app and tells it to update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is **not** possible for a WP app to receive such updates from Facebook.
Because you don't have any such API for the purpose.

**What about RealTime API ?**
Well, it is possible to get Realtime updates from facebook using that API, but it requires you to specify a `callback Url`. In other words, it require you to have a web server with an **web application** that can accept `GET` and `POST` requests from server. After receiving such updates, **your webapp** can broadcast updates to device using `PUSH Notification Service`.

**Any Workaround ?**
Yes ane workaround can be to use a periodic task that runs and fetch data after regular intervals. But beware of:

- Amount of Data you send in periodic Task (Battery + Data Consideration).
- Reliability factor of Periodic Tasks (Thay may not run at all).

Comment: Thank you so much for replying. There is so less info on the web on this! So, if I were to use a WCF service hosted on web to receive updates and then `PUSH` changed data somehow to my mobile app will that work?

Comment: Ofcourse it will work, provided you follow the requirements and procedures documented in Facebook's API. You can also use services such as appharbour, Google App Engine, Heroku and many else, depending upon your programming capabilities.

Comment: I am following this [article](http://alexandernorway.blogspot.com/2012/08/facebook-real-time-api-tutorial.html) to test the whether I can actually get the updates. But after attempting to subscribe I get `(#2200) callback verification failed: ` error. Could you please suggest what I can do? I uploaded the php file to the hosting of a website of a client.

Comment: I searched a few resources and found that this may occur due to a variety of reasons. A few prominent ones are: server not reachable externally for verification or some coding error. Here's a special note for PHP devs on FB [page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/).
If problem still persists, ask a new question with detailed code to gather more discussion.